# Xcode doesn't find third part library

Tags: c, xcode, macos, shared-libraries

I'm trying to install on my Mac a third-part dynamic library. I've got the header and the shared library xxx.dylib. I've put into /usr/local/include the header and in /usr/local/lib the xxx.dylib, but when in Xcode I try to include the library (in this way: ) the compiler tell me that he cannot find anything. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have to add /usr/local/include and /usr/local/lib to the Xcode  Header Search Paths and Library Search Paths settings.